# R: sequence of substituted expressions from sequence of values

Tags: r, expression, quote

I want to produce

```
list(quote(10^2), quote(10^3), quote(10^4),
     quote(10^5), quote(10^6), quote(10^7))
```

from

```
seq(2,7)
```

is there a less gawdawful way to do that than

```
mapply(function(n) substitute(10^x, list(x=as.double(n))), seq(2,7))
```

? I have tried the following:

```
> substitute(10^x, list(x=seq(2,7)))
10^2:7

> mapply(substitute, 10^x, x=seq(2,7))
Error in mapply(substitute, 10^x, x = seq(2, 7)) : object 'x' not found

> mapply(function(n) substitute(10^n), seq(2,7))
list(10^dots[[1L]][[6L]], 10^dots[[1L]][[6L]], 10^dots[[1L]][[6L]], 
     10^dots[[1L]][[6L]], 10^dots[[1L]][[6L]], 10^dots[[1L]][[6L]])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `bquote`:

```
lapply(as.numeric(2:7), function(x) bquote(10^.(x)))
```

Comment: That works quite nicely and it turns out I don't even need the `as.numeric`.

Comment: Can you explain whether there is an advantage to `bquote` over `substitute` for something like this?

Comment: I think its just a matter of which syntax you prefer.  `bquote` uses `substitute`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do:

```
lapply(2:7, function(x) {
  substitute(10^x, list(x = x))
})
```

---

Example:

```
test <- lapply(2:7, function(x) {
  substitute(10^x, list(x = x))
})
str(test)
# List of 6
#  $ : language 10^2L
#  $ : language 10^3L
#  $ : language 10^4L
#  $ : language 10^5L
#  $ : language 10^6L
#  $ : language 10^7L

orig <- list(quote(10^2), quote(10^3), quote(10^4),
             quote(10^5), quote(10^6), quote(10^7))
str(orig)
# List of 6
#  $ : language 10^2
#  $ : language 10^3
#  $ : language 10^4
#  $ : language 10^5
#  $ : language 10^6
#  $ : language 10^7
```

The only difference there is that my version treats the values 2:7 as integers (hence the "L").